# How to mock a constructor class using Mockery

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, stripe-payments, mockery

I attempted to mock the `StripeClient` class in Laravel using `Mockery` and the `app()` helper. While I managed to mock the `balance->retrieve` method and simulate responses successfully, I encountered issues when trying to mock the constructor.

When using the `app()` helper to initiate `StripeClient` with constructor parameters, the constructor wasn't being mocked as expected.

Instead, the actual constructor was being called, leading to invalid key errors due to missing secrets. My aim was to control the Stripe API calls in unit tests, but I'm struggling to mock the constructor parameters and ensuring the desired behavior.

This is how I am initiating `StripeClient` in the `Stripe` service:

```php
$this->stripeClient = app(StripeClient::class, [
    'config' => $this->stripeSecretKey,
]);
```

I want to retrieve the balance:

```php
$balance = $this->stripeClient
    ->balance
    ->retrieve(
        [],
        ['stripe_account' => $stripeAccountId]
    )
    ->toArray();
```

After some research, I found that Stripe calls request method behind the scenes when I call `->balance->retrieve`.

So I tried to mock this as below in the test case:

```php
$this->instance(
    StripeClient::class,
    \Mockery::mock(
        StripeClient::class,
        function (MockInterface $mock): void {
            $mock->shouldReceive('request')
                ->zeroOrMoreTimes()
                ->andReturn([
                    'available' => [
                        'amount' => 1000,
                    ],
                    'livemode' => false,
                ]);
        }
    )
);
```

This works when I call `->balance->retrieve` by initiating the `StripeClient` as below (i.e. without passing the config param):

```php
$stripeClient = app(StripeClient::class);
```

But when I pass a config param, it calls the original `__construct` method of `StripeClient` and throws the invalid key error:

```php
$stripeClient = app(StripeClient::class, [
    'config' => 'key',
]);
```

So I tried to mock the `__construct` as well like below but it seems it is not working. It's still calling the original constructor:

```php
$mock->shouldReceive('__construct')
    ->with([
        'config' => 'key',
    ])
    ->zeroOrMoreTimes()
    ->andReturnSelf();
```

Comment: I had this issue in the past, but I cannot remember how I fixed it (this happened to me in another class, but is the same principle, if you have `app(class, array)`, it will literally ignore your mock). I will be able to try to help you in a few hours, sorry for that